# Json error of undefine when using for loop

Tags: json

im learning JSON and encounter a problem when looping JSON.
This is my JSON response

```
{
"success": 1,
"category": [{
    "id": "1",
    "category": "Editorial",
    "created_at": "2019-11-05 18:10:31",
    "firstname": "abc",
    "lastname": "xyz"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "category": "Sports",
    "created_at": "2019-11-05 19:25:50",
    "firstname": "abc",
    "lastname": "xyz"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "category": "Health",
    "created_at": "2019-11-05 19:27:23",
    "firstname": "abc",
    "lastname": "xyz"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "category": "Food",
    "created_at": "2019-11-05 19:39:17",
    "firstname": "abc",
    "lastname": "xyz"
}]}
```

and this is my loop

```
for(var i = 0; i <= jsonData.category.length; i++){
      console.log(jsonData.category[i]['firstname']);}
```

it does print in console but it gives me this error

> Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined
>       at Object.success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<` instead of `<=`. Otherwise you reach an undefined index.

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.category.length; i++){
  console.log(jsonData.category[i]['firstname']);
}
```

Comment: Index inside an array are defined from 0 to length - 1, like in other programming language (c/c++, java, php, etc...), an array containing [4,5,6] contains 3 index 0, 1, 2, array[0] == 4, array[1] == 5, array[2] == 6,  array[3] == undefined